# Error using AJAX in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm newbie. I have the following code:

**File PHP:**

```
<div class="video" id="result"></div>
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'player.php',
        data: {
            id: 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=fY7RT9_QM1a'
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
</script>
```

**File PHP:**

```html
function Demoplugin_jw($link) {
 $Demoplayer .= "
 <script type='text/javascript' src='".plugins_url(
                      'player/Jwplayer7/jwplayer.js', __FILE__)."'></script>
 <div id='jw'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('jw').setup({
   primary: 'html5',
   width: '100%px',
   height: '100%px',
   aspectratio: '16:9',
   skin: 'bekle',
   sources: ".Demoplugin($link)."
        })
    </script>";
 return $Demoplayer;
}
function Demoplugin($link){
    .....
    ....
    $sources .= {file:"'.$value.'",type:"mp4",label:"'.$key.'"};
    $sources = '['.rtrim($sources, ',').']';
    return $sources;
}

if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
 echo Demoplugin_jw($_POST['id']);
}
```

I want show result of function `Demoplugin_jw` to the `<div id="result">`.

But I getting error:

```
alert("error")
```

Comment: Are you sure that your js file is loaded properly with no error in console?

Comment: you're missing `header('Content-type: javascript/json');` if you're returning a response.

Comment: This is no good `$Demoplayer .=` you have to assign it before doing `.=` so `=` first or you get a undefined variable warning in PHP 5.5 ish

Comment: You will only get to the .error() section if the server returns a 404 ( not found ) or 500 ( internal error ), maybe some others but those are the most common.

Comment: @ Shubhranshu I sure!

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thank you!

Comment: @JaromandaX - typically it's gonna be a request error though.  I never get them anymore, so .....

Comment: @justcntt - thanks what was the issue>?

Comment: YOu do know that error callback takes arguments ...`jqXHR, textStatus, error` ... log those to the console to get useful debugging information

Comment: @KDOT Where i must add this?

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved in JavaScript since it is a JavaScript API. Here, we save the YouTube v GET value in a `data` attribute. This then assigns the ID to the wrapping div holding the video and uses that data as the ID so you can have multiple videos on one page.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.youtube-link').click(function() {
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.id = $(this).attr('data');
    $(this).append(wrapper);
    var $sources = {
      file: 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=' + $(this).attr('data'),
      type: 'mp4'
    };
    jwplayer($(this).attr('data')).setup({
      primary: 'html5',
      width: '100%px',
      height: '100%px',
      aspectratio: '16:9',
      skin: 'bekle',
      sources: $sources
    });
  });
  $('.youtube-link').forEach(function($link) {
      $($link.attr('data')).click(function() {
          $(this).remove();
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.youtube-link {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- todo: add this link -->
<script src="link_to_your_jwPlayer"></script>

<div class="youtube-link" data="JzYRZygjJrI">Watch JzYRZygjJrI</div>
<div class="youtube-link" data="wySpzs5S1Eg">Watch wySpzs5S1Eg</div>
```

This is not tested code since I do not have access to the `jwplayer.js` file. Just change this as you need to. PS - you'll need to add the styling.

Comment: Thank for answer! But I want use AJAX. And I get source video from youtube, i not get iframe

Comment: but all you're doing is passing in the link as a function, using AJAX is just a slower and less maintainable process. Also, it is abit clear to see that your PHP skills arn't very good so why make things harder when you can just have it working? @justcntt

Comment: I wan't hide id: 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=fY7RT9_QM1a', can you help me again?

Comment: I added a way of clicking the video to delete it (see updated answer), you can expand and create a close button by finding the closest video player @justcntt